# how to set onClick() for buttons using in header text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

In my program i am using back and order button in header, i have shown back button on left side and order button on right side of header, but now i want to make these buttons click able to call different activities, i know how to call different activities using button click, but in this situation i don't have any idea how to make button click able within header, so please see the below xml code which i am using as a header:-

```
       <TextView
   android:id="@+id/actionbar"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dip"
   android:background="@drawable/header"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back"
   android:drawableRight="@drawable/final_order"
   android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
   android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
   android:shadowDx="1"
   android:shadowDy="1"
   android:shadowRadius="1"
   android:text="Pizza"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:textSize="25dp"
   android:textStyle="bold" />
```

please write some code in brief to achieve that taget..... Thanks

Comment: What do you mean button in header? I only see one TextView (header?)

Comment: Carnal i have written clearly --- how to set onClick() for buttons using in header text